# Система меток: шаг первый

Tags: обсуждение

В настоящее время на сайте есть очень много разных меток, которые зачастую избыточны. Предлагаю начать наводить порядок. С полным списком меток вы можете ознакомиться в [соответствующем разделе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/tags).

Пожалуйста, напишите здесь о том, что, по-вашему, сейчас нужно сделать в первую очередь. Чтобы вы могли лучше понять, что из себя представляет система меток, оставлю полезные ссылки:

- [Что такое метки и как их использовать?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)
- [Подробнее о привилегии](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags)
- [Что должно содержать краткое описание метки?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts)
- [Создание синонимов **(важно!)**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms)
- [Принятие описаний меток](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits)
- [Метки: множественное или единственное число?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE)
- [Как правильно составлять описание метки (tag wiki)? Что туда включать?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/527/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-tag-wiki-%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Мне кажется, что система меток в "Русском языке" **может иметь большое значение, если ее правильно организовать.** В настоящий момент лично я метками не пользуюсь, так как с их помощью я не могу найти даже те вопросы, на которые отвечала сама. Иногда встречается повтор вопросов, но их тоже очень сложно найти, и метки в этом нисколько не помогают. Вот, к примеру,  метка "пунктуация" с числом 2345 ― что можно найти по этой метке?

**Получается, что сайт, накопивший значительный ресурс ценных знаний, не может организовать их достойное хранение и систематизацию**, он похож на библиотеку, в которой нет системного каталога, так можно ли в таком книгохранилище что-нибудь найти?

**Итак, метки могут быть простой формальностью,  а могут превратить форум в энциклопедию русского языка,** так как ответы здесь полные, развернутые, организованные в виде дискуссии если не академиками, то достаточно знающими, ответственными и заинтересованными людьми. Такого нет ни на одном другом сайте (очень часто это просто реплики, разговоры, ответы совсем мало знающих  людей или, напротив, ответы специалистов в форме тех же реплик).

**Нужны системные метки, и организовать их не трудно,** так как русский язык уже имеет разделы: грамматика, орфография, пунктуация, словообразование, лексика, фразеология и т.д., а в каждом разделе есть всем знакомые темы. **Можно взять за основу наличие трех меток: первая метка ― это раздел, вторая метка ― тема раздела, третья ― более свободного и конкретного содержания.** Краткая инструкция "Как ставить метки" с перечнем разделов и тем  будет прилагаться.

Answer (score 3):

Согласен, что с метками порядка нет и проблему нужно бы решить, и чем скорее тем лучше. Не берусь разработать систему, но если найдется такой герой, который это сделает (например, взяв предложение @Sharon за основу), я постараюсь посильно помочь в ее внедрении.