# О примении метки "как"

Tags: обсуждение

Количество вопросов растет, а это значит, что возрастает роль заголовков и меток как ориентиров в этом безбрежном море. В свободное время я стараюсь изменять заголовки (делать их более информативными) и добавлять метки к вопросам. В частности, стараюсь добавить метку "как" ко всем вопросам, связанным с употреблением этого слова. Вдруг обнаружил, что наш уважаемый администратор эту метку убрал. Давайте согласуем наши действия; если есть необходимость - уточним предназначение этой метки.

Answer (score 1):

Я убрал эту метку, потому что непонятно, когда и зачем она должна применяться. Почему тогда не введены метки "словно", "как-будто", "точно", "будто", "в-качестве" и т. п.?

Вообще говоря, то, каким правилом руководствоваться при добавлении меток, не очень понятно. Я пытался призвать к обсуждению этого вопроса: [Система меток: шаг первый](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/179/178412). Вроде бы и предложение там есть, но никакого фидбэка: вопросов, комментариев, дополнений — нет. Нужно либо принять те правила, которые предложила Сибилла, либо разработать другие.

Если вы считаете, что метка "как" нужна, [предложите](https://rus.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/3527), пожалуйста, ее описание и руководство.

Comment: Дымаю, что метка нужна (пока не создана другая система меток), так как вопросов и ответов, связанных с употреблением слова "как", накопилось огромное множество, а метка помогает увидеть многогранность этой непростой темы. У меня нет опыта в описании меток, лучше бы профессионал это делал. Подождем, может какая рыбка и заглотнет этот крючек. А если нет, то на безрыбье придется медведю становиться рыбой. :))

Comment: Предложил описание метки. Прошу проверить.