# Метки, связанные с сочетаемостью

Tags: обсуждение

Есть три похожие метки: сочетаемость, лексическая-сочетаемость, стилист.-сочетаемость. Когда их употреблять? В чем отличие между ними?

Answer (score 0):

О том, в чем разница между этими понятиями, можно почитать, например, здесь: http://www.textologia.ru/russkiy/kultura-rechi/tochnost-rechi/?q=596. Употреблять данные метки стоит в подходящих случаях :)

Comment: Согласно этому усточнику *сочетаемость* - общая метка, а под ней должно быть три: лексическая, грамматическая (синтаксическая) и стилистическая. Получается, одной метки не хватает.

Comment: @М_Г а в чем смысл метки «сочетаемость»?

Comment: Я надеялся, Вы мне объясните...Но раз уж Вы спрашиваете как  я это понимаю, то сочетаемость - родовое понятие, а под ним - три вида сочетаемости. Нужны ли такие "родовые" метки - это к вопросу о структуризации всей системы наших меток.

Comment: @М_Г то, что вы назвали «родовой системой меток», применимо только к разделам языкознания: лексика, стилистика, грамматика...

Comment: Я готов принять любую систему, лишь бы логичной была. Вашу логику не совсем понимаю (скупо излагаете). Вы хотите построить двухуровневую систему? На верхнем уровне  - разделы языкознания? Тогда "лексическая сочетаемость" пойдет под "лексику", а "стилистическая сочетаемость" - под "стилистику"? А третья метка должна быть "грамматическая сочетаемость" (вместо просто "сочетаемость")?

Comment: @М_Г это не моя логика: https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/a/180/178412. Нет; да; да; да, третьей меткой должна быть "грамматическая-сочетаемость".

Comment: Идея развести виды сочетаемости в разные разделы языкознания мне не нравится. Точно определить вид сочетаемости нелегко (см. ваш источник), а общей метки не будет. Я предлагаю добавить метку "грамматическая-сочетаемость" (у нас будет метка для каждого вида сочетаемости), а просто "сочетаемость" присваивать всем таким вопросам как вторую метку .

Comment: @М_Г зачем каждому вопрос просто присваивать метку «сочетаемость»? Нужно наоборот присваивать как можно более точные метки, а сочетаемость, очевидно, расплывчата. Я согласен, что нужно создать грамматическую метку.